# Struggling with 2D arrays in assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, spim, pcspim

I am trying to implement the following in MIPS

X is a two-dimensional array (matrix) of double-precision floating-point
numbers and Y is two-dimensional array of 32-bit integers. 
Trying to write code for the following

```
Z= (X[i][j] + Y[i][j])
```

Now I dont know how to declare these arrays in MIPS:

So far I have written some of the main program but dont know how to implement them in the `.data` section

```
.data

.text
.main:
mtc1 $0, $f0
 cvt.d.w $f0, $f0
  # $a1 is the address of the first element of x
  l.a $r1, $a1
  # $a2 is the address of the first element of y
  l.a $r2, $a2
  addi $r4, $0, 30
  add.d $f8, $f0, $f0
```

Comment: How about finding and reading assembly documentation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [is it possible to declare such 2D arrays in MIPS assembly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828209/is-it-possible-to-declare-such-2d-arrays-in-mips-assembly)

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze - I did but cant find any information

Comment: @PaulR - That question is no more visible.

Comment: @ArjunShankar Amber Arroway has deleted it.

Comment: I cant delete questions, my reputation is too low?

Comment: @Amber: you shouldn't really delete questions if people have already gone to the trouble of providing answers. Instead of posting an almost duplicate question you should have gone back and edited the original question to improve it and get more/better answers.

Comment: @PaulR my rep is too low to delete anything...

Comment: @Amber: no it's not - you can delete your own questions apparently - on the deleted question it even says: **deleted by Amber Arroway 1 hour ago**, so it's a little disingenuous of you to claim that you didn't or couldn't delete it.

Answer (score 0):

2D arrays aren't that bad. The trick is to deal with one dimension at a time. If you have the size of each element, and the size of each dimension, the math is simple. Add the product of the row index(zero based), row size and element size (in bytes) to your base address. This will be the base address of the row you want. Add the product of the column index and element size to that and you have the address of the element.

As for the data segment, just reserve the total size of the array. For example if you need space for a 3x4, reserve 12 elements. If you're using integers, array: .word 0:12 will do what you need.

Comment: 2D arrays are that bad. They eat your babies. They cause global warming, hurricanes, athlete's foot, itches behind your ear and thunderstorms whenever Thor encounters one. They're an abomination of C/C++ programming and every true assembly programmer should shun them. Compiler output contains no 2D arrays. Assembly addressing modes know nothing about 2D arrays. If Turing had wanted us to use 2D arrays he'd invented the floppy disk not the tape. How hard is it to translate from `(x, y)` to `x + width * y` ...